# How to unblock transaction set a 0 fee (mistake) on Mist wallet?

Tags: mist

I believe I did a mistake while doing a transaction from a wallet contract on Mist wallet.

I wanted to do a transaction, but I did it with 0 fee, so of course the transaction never reached the blockchain.

I did an other transaction from the same wallet contract to same address previously used on the transaction with higher fee which went through. The first transaction is still stuck.

Is there anything I can do to cancel or fix the this transaction ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your 0 fee transaction will be in the mempool until it is accepted. This is unlikely because of the fee. Alternatively, it will be rejected if the account you are sending from doesn't have the funds, otherwise it will be removed once it reaches a timeout. I am unsure how long this is for Ethereum, I think for Bitcoin it is around 2 weeks.

Depending on what the transaction was for you might want to clear that account just incase your 0 fee transaction is accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I clear that account ?

Comment: I mean send the Ether to another account you own with an appropriate fee so it will hopefully be accepted before the one you made by mistake.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the Ether is not on my wallet anymore, the wallet shows 0 ETH

Comment: How much Ether did you have in the account originally? How much did you attempt to send and to where? Could you specify the account address for me? If you look up the account address on this site: https://etherscan.io/ you can see it's status on the current network.

Comment: Sure, so this wallet contract contains other coins too. I attempted to send .69202992 ETHER to 0x93025150b13Eb744D51d927549a30630912E8Fe8 (SONM ico). I have no TxID, has the transaction never reached the blockchain. [Link of Screenshot ](http://imgur.com/hMVrh05)

Comment: If the transaction is never accepted the funds should appear at the send address.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, completely forgot to reply. So what happened is that I needed to add the contract of the token, then it automatically appeared in my wallet :)